# Azure pipeline Command Line Script error showing - mv: cannot stat No such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using sample template project of ASP Dot NET MVC Core and inside the project React was installed. I need to deploy this project to Azure using CI/CD Pipelines.

I can able to success all jobs except command line script. In command line script job, just want to move my react "build" folder to "wwwroot" folder for navigating react index page.

[This is the tutorial I've used.](https://www.kambu.pl/blog/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-together-with-net-backend-to-azure-with-azure-devops/)

> Package.json

[image: Package json]

> Code Structure

[image]

> Repos

[image]

> Pipeline - npm build

[image]

> Pipeline - Command Line Script

[image]

> Command Line Script

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the blog tutorial, you are not successful because the blog is not talking about SPA.

He created two projects using two commands. I have personally tested and found that when using VS2022 to publish a SPA project, the project structure is as follows.

[image]

[image]

We can find that after the release, the React project in ClientApp will be automatically added to the wwwroot in the Asp.net Core project after compilation.

---

So I think, if you use two separate projects, like in the blog, then we need to use mv command to copy the file content.

If we are using a SPA project, the same project you created now, you can omit these steps and publish it normally.

Comment: In my requirement there should not be two separate projects. I'm currently trying to workout with combination of MVC core with React like in the image attached. AS you said, I tried to publish it normally without the command line script. But in this process we can able to browse MVC pages but not React. Actually don't know how to workout this.

Comment: @ganesh Of course I know what you are doing now, as my last sentence mentioned, I think we just need to publish the asp.net core with react.js project normally. No need to refer to the blog you provided.

Comment: @ganesh In my answer, just explain why you encountered the current problem? This is because the reference blog is two separate projects, which are completely different from the spa project you are using now.

Comment: So in my scenario, I need to remove command line script, dotnet restore, build, publish steps in Agent job and publish to Azure. Is that the correct way?

Comment: @ganesh Yes, I think normal publishing will do.

Comment: But how we able to browse React Pages after publish to Azure. Because MVC pages only showing in the Startup but not React and we currently didn't give any navigations to React pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245066/discussion-between-jason-and-ganesh).

Answer (score 0):

Use self checkout in your yaml pipeline.